# How to use the linqdatasource.delete method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

TLDR: How do I use the "oldValues" parameter in the linqdatasource.delete() method? (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.delete?view=netframework-4.7.2))

> oldValues IDictionary The row values that are evaluated to detect data
>   conflicts.

I have a ListBox which is bound to a linqdatasouce. When I press a button, I want the item that is selected in the listbox, to be deleted from the linqdatasource. As suggested by the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.delete?view=netframework-4.7.2) of the linqdatasource.delete method I tried to do it by just removing the item from the list (see code below). However, with this, the item was removed from the listbox but not deleted from the linqdatasource.

How exactly do I now use the linqdatasource.delete() method? It's mainly the "oldValues" parameter that I don't understand.

```
protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    listboxSelectedArtikel.Items.Remove(listboxSelectedArtikel.SelectedItem);
    listboxSelectedArtikel.DataBind();
}
```